# How do I create a email confirmation?

Tags: ruby, email, registration, confirmation-email, email-confirmation

I'm trying to make a simple email notification when a user signs up.

My user sign up works fine, and I followed the ["Sending Email"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email) tutorial exactly but can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

user_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_filter :admin_only

  actions :index, :show, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy
  respond_to :html

#  def new
#    @user = User.new(:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token])
#    @user.email = @user.invitation.recipient_email  
#  end  

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    UserMailer.deliver_registration_confirmation(@user) < -- where I added the mailer
    @user.save(false)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{ redirect_to admin_users_path}
    end

  end

  private

  def collection
    paginate_options ||= {}
    paginate_options[:page] ||= (params[:page] || 1)
    paginate_options[:per_page] ||= (params[:per_page] || 20)
    @search = User.search(params[:search])
    @users ||= @search.all.paginate(paginate_options)
  end
end
```

environments/production.rb

```
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'alpine.totaline.com' }

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

# set delivery method to :smtp, :sendmail or :test
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

# these options are only needed if you choose smtp delivery
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port           => 25,
  :domain         => 'alpine.totaline.com',
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name      => 'emailname@gmail.com',
  :password       => 'thepassword'
}
```

models/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    recipients  user.email
    from        "webmaster@alpinechallenge.com"
    subject     "Thank you for Registering"
    body        "You are now registered on the Alpine Challenge!"
  end  
end
```

Comment: Are you sure `alp.domain..com` is right? It doesn't look right.

Comment: @Beau Grantham UserMailer.deliver_registration_confirmation(@user) - Its just not sending the email. everything looks to be set up properly

Comment: @Greg yeah the domain was set up right when I had it running I just changed it chen I posted it here but ty I will double check jus to make sure

Comment: ty for the comments guys.. this is getting fown to the wire and I can't get a simple email confirmation to work.. what gives?!

Comment: is there any more information I can give that can help diagnose the problem? Please I really need help with this like really, really badly

Comment: You might want to take a look at this gem, pony: https://github.com/benprew/pony .. a little bit simpler than ActionMailer; one line send command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like for Gmail you need to use port 587:

```
# these options are only needed if you choose smtp delivery
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port           => '587',
  :domain         => 'alpine.totaline.com',
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name      => 'emailname@gmail.com',
  :password       => 'thepassword'
}
```

[This page contains notes about configuring mail clients for usage with Gmail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287).